# Make RSA encrypted chat application android

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am working on a chat application, made in Java for android. I have a server created in python, using twisted, and of course, in my android app I have the client implemented.

It's working very well, but I want to make it secure. I was looking at RSA encryption and found this link: http://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/rsa-encryption-example/

The problem is that, I can make a pair of keys, a private key that will be on the server to decrypt the messages and the public key will hard-coded (or somewhere online), in the android application. The problem would be, when the server sends the message back to the client, how will he be able to get it ? That one needs to be send encrypted as well, otherwise, there's no point in doing it. I was thinking about creating a pair of keys for each client, but ... I think it's not the best approach.

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: The usual approach is to not reinvent the wheel but just use SSL, which fits perfectly with the model you're proposing. Don't forget if you hard-code the public key into the client, you're going to be in a lot of pain if your private key is ever compromised.

Comment: I haven't found something straight to the point example of what I need, of SSL and java (especially an android app)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is usually to create a form of *Public Key Infrastructure* (PKI), where the public keys of the clients can be verified when needed. You can do this by putting them into a certificate and sign it by some kind of *certificate authority* (CA) that you control. That way you don't need to store all the certificates, and you can also revoke certificates of clients that have their key compromised. This is what is normally used by (browser) TLS, especially if *client authentication* is deployed.

*Key management* however is a large topic that cannot be handled within one answer.

Comment: If this is only for data encryption and not for authentication, OP doesn't need client keys/certificates at all.

Comment: @divanov Certificates are also used for asymmetric encryption. What makes you think they aren't? There is even a specific bit in the key usage extensions if the key can be used for encryption or not.

Comment: For chat one obviously wants to make symmetric session key and use it for encryption.

Comment: @divanov Really? In that case the title and question text seems a bit flawed. Besides that, you can encrypt a session key with the public key, although at least two session keys is better for two way communication. You need of course authenticated (EC)DH for perfect forwarding secrecy. But all this is a bit inconsequential if you don't get key management right in the first place.

Comment: And all these are already implemented in SSL as Dark Falcon mentioned ;)